# Can I dock a div against another div in IE 8?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, docking

Consider this page: http://losthobbit.net/temp/docking.html

Here's the HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0; top: 0; width: 259; background-color: #00FF00">
        <input type="button" style="position: absolute; left: 161; top: 30; width: 75; height: 25"/>  
    </div>    
    <div style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 259; left: 0; height: 100; background-color: #00FFFF">
        <input type="button" style="position: absolute; right: 10; top: 30; width: 75; height: 25"/>  
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In Chrome & FireFox this works perfectly.  The second div docks against the first div.

Is it possible to get this working in IE8?

Thank you in advance, wonderful people :)

Comment: As mentioned last time you asked a question about this code: *fix your machine detectable errors*! There are problems with both the [HTML](http://validator.w3.org/) and the [CSS](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/)

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I didn't see your comment.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add units for example "px" to your css values. IE likes it more that way, not so forgiving as FF or Ch :)

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/X2QYs/

Try this, does what you have asked.

Not sure why you would ever want to do that though, is not like any webpage design I have seen before.